# Adjoint of T $\in B(\ell^{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I was wondering if you guys can help me with this one!

Let $T \in B(\ell^{2})$ a continuous operator. Also,

\begin{align*}
(Ts)(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{t}_{m=1} s(m),\hspace{1cm}n\in \mathbb{N}, s\in \ell^{2}
\end{align*}

What is the adjoint of $T$?

PS: Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sure that You have $t$ and not $n$ as the upper summation index?

Comment: What i know is that the adjoint $T^{*}$ has to satisfy the following $\left<T^{*}f,x\right>=\left<f,Tx\right>$ but i get confused when i'm try to assign the arguments :(

Comment: @PeterMelech no, i´m not. Is a proposed exercise that i find on internet. But since $(T o s)$ depend on $n$, actually make me sense. What if so?

Comment: The map, as you have currently defined it, looks like
$$
Ts = \left(\sum_{m=1}^t s(m)\right) \cdot (1, \frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 14 , \dots)
$$
which is fairly simple looking.  I suspect that Peter is right, and that the upper summation was supposed to be $n$ rather than $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f,s\in\ell^2$ then 
$$\langle f,Ts\rangle =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\overline{s_m}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}f_n\right)\overline{s_m}.$$
So define $$T^{*}f(n)=\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}f_m$$
which is well defined since
$$\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{m}f_m|\leq |\{\frac{1}{m}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}|_{\ell²}|f|_{\ell^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}|f|_{\ell^2}<\infty$$
by Cauchy-Schwartz. The first equation shows this is the adjoint operator. If $t$ is  $n$ which seemed natural to me ( taking the average of the first $n$ numbers in the sequence)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just a last ask. I'm having troubles with the notation. What is $\overline{s_{m}}$ actually?

Comment: the complex conjugate, if you consider sequences of complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume
$$Ts(n) = \frac1n \sum_{m=1}^n s(m)$$
Then $$\langle Ts, r\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n  \sum_{m=1}^ns(m)r(n) = \sum_{\substack{n,m\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 1}\\ 1\le m\le n}} \frac 1n s(m)r(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty s(m) \sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{r(n)}n$$
so the adjoint operator is at least formally

$$T^* r(m) := \sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{r(n)}n$$
This is finite for each $m$ due to Fubini's theorem and the above computation.
Is it a bounded operator on $\ell^2$? Yes, if $T$ is bounded, since
$$ \|T^* r\|_{\ell^2} = \sup_{\|s\|_{\ell^2} = 1} |\langle s, T^*r\rangle | = \sup_{\|s\|_{\ell^2} = 1} |\langle Ts, r\rangle | \le \|r\|_{\ell^2}  \|T\| $$

Why is $T$ bounded? Because of the discrete [Hardy's inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality)